# C# wrappers and web applications

Tags: c#

Hi is it possible for me to wrap a web application in C# to enable it to be interactive as a desktop application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is *possible* but would be very hard to accomplish.

You would need an instance `HttpContext` and every service it provides.

You may consider using a desktop application as a *client* of a web service instead - depending on what exactly you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

one way that might be considered is to use silverlight/wpf to have an application or flavors of an application that can run in a browser or on the desktop.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to host the web application on a web server like IIS or Apache. If you are trying to host a PHP based application, you can install PHP on most web servers.  Once you have the application hosted you will need to write an application to function as a web browser.

MSDN has an old example of how to do this here: [Web Browser Express](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379558%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

There are a couple code project options as well: [SimpleWebBrowser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/SimpleWebBrowser.aspx), [WBrowser](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/WBrowser.aspx)